# How can I fake HDMI signal?

Tags: hdmi

Is it possible to build a circuit to send power to an hdmi-in port on a repurposed tv power/logic board to make the “unit/logic board” see it as a signal and not turn off? I’m making a video key light using the back lights and main board power from an old tv. After 15 minutes of “no signal” the UNIT turns off.

Comment: You can probably disable that on the tv menu, otherwise https://hackaday.com/2020/06/02/an-open-source-hdmi-implementation-for-fpgas/

Comment: What model ? ??

Comment: you're not talking about *faking* a signal, you're actually trying to generate a signal!

Comment: That question is a result of an X-Y problem. You just want to keep a backlight on, regardless of it being still connected to original TV circuitry. You know it can be kept on by giving it a HDMI signal. So you ask about generating HDMI, which is not the problem you originally want solved. Sure, it must be possible to disconnect TV circuits and just have the backlight turned on all the time. But you need TV schematics for that, we don't know which TV you have and even if we did we don't have the schematics for it, so you would have to reverse-engineer it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a low cost solution, I would consider one of the $25 Android TV boxes.  If you boot it up and turn off the screen saver, auto power off etc, you should be able to get an HDMI signal out continuously.  You may be able to auto launch an app the output the video continuously as well, or just during your wakeup cycle - maybe $30.

Alternative may be to get a cheap Xilinx Zedboard and generate the HDMI using Xilinx-supplied IP.

Good luck

Comment: There is no lcd. I have a lot of fire sticks and I have one plugged in now but it’s a waste of a good device to just have it attached to the back of a video light. There has to be a way to run a voltage or resistor in to get it to stay on